# Kong External Service: no Route matched with those values

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-ingress

## TL;DR

I followed each step of the [External Service tutorial](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/3.0.x/guides/services/external/), but when I try to send and HTTP request to `http://localhost/httpbin/anything`, I get the "no Route matched with those values." error message.

Is the guide outdated? Is it missing some step?

## Long Version

### Kong Setup

I've setup Kong Gateway on a local Kubernetes cluster, with minikube:

```bash
minikube start --driver=docker
```

```
# In another terminal window/in a background process
minikube tunnel
```

Gateway API CRDs:

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gateway-api/releases/download/v1.0.0/standard-install.yaml
```

```bash
echo "
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: GatewayClass
metadata:
 name: kong
 annotations:
   konghq.com/gatewayclass-unmanaged: 'true'

spec:
 controllerName: konghq.com/kic-gateway-controller
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
 name: kong
spec:
 gatewayClassName: kong
 listeners:
 - name: proxy
   port: 80
   protocol: HTTP
" | kubectl apply -f -
```

Kong installation with helm:

```bash
helm repo add kong https://charts.konghq.com
helm repo update
helm install kong kong/ingress -n kong --create-namespace
```

Testing connectivity:

```bash
export PROXY_IP=$(kubectl get svc --namespace kong kong-gateway-proxy -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
echo $PROXY_IP
curl -i $PROXY_IP
```

### External Service Configuration

I've consensed the Service and HTTPRoute in the same YAML:

```yaml
---
# Service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: proxy-to-httpbin
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: httpbin.org

---
# Route /httpbin
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: proxy-from-k8s-to-httpbin
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: kong
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: 
        value: /httpbin
    backendRefs:
    - name: proxy-to-httpbin
      kind: Service
      port: 80
```

and applied it:

```bash
$ kubectl apply -f ./external-service.yaml
service/proxy-to-httpbin created
httproute.gateway.networking.k8s.io/proxy-from-k8s-to-httpbin created
```

Result:

```bash
$ kubectl get services
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
proxy-to-httpbin   ExternalName   <none>          httpbin.org   80/TCP                       8m1s

$ kubectl get httproutes
NAME                        HOSTNAMES   AGE
proxy-from-k8s-to-httpbin               8m51s
```

### Problem

The guide states that after these steps, when [testing the service](http://httpbin.org/anything) you should get a response similiar to what you would receive from http://httpbin.org/anything.

But when I send an HTTP request to gateway-proxy/httpbin/anything, I get the "no route" error:

```bash
$ curl -s -i $PROXY_IP/httpbin/anything
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 52
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 2023 15:58:39 GMT
X-Kong-Response-Latency: 0
Server: kong/3.4.2
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 9
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 1
Via: kong/3.4.2

{
  "message":"no Route matched with those values"
}
```

### Question

How can I make the Gateway forward correctly my HTTP requests to the external service?

### Update

I deployed Kong on [AKS](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/install/cloud/aks/), with the same configuration, and the external service `httpbin` now does work:

```bash
curl -s -i 4.232.X.X/httpbin/anything
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 480
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache-Key: c48fe84b97bba1516dd96c93604fc907de95cf449284992594d1325998236ffb
X-Cache-Status: Bypass
Date: Fri, 01 Dec 2023 10:22:10 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 504
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 1
Via: kong/3.4.2

{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Host": "4.232.X.X",
    "User-Agent": "curl/8.2.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6569b3d1-7a71e89914522ebe73d9d548",
    "X-Forwarded-Host": "4.232.X.X",
    "X-Forwarded-Path": "/httpbin/anything",
    "X-Forwarded-Prefix": "/httpbin/"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "origin": "10.224.0.4, 4.232.X.Y",
  "url": "http://4.232.X.X/anything"
}
```

So I guess this might have something to do with minikube